# apt dependies for pypi package

Tags: python, pypi

Question about the policy of installing third-party binary dependencies missing from pypi.

There is a package distributed via pypi, depending on the set of libraries from the debian repository of debian packages (apt install).
Without these libraries, the package will not work / install. How to install / ask the user to install these libraries.

What is community policy on this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The most correct way is to distribute your packages in the proper system package format — rpm, deb, whatever. Those formats allow to declare other system dependencies so that package managers automatically resolve dependencies version and install the dependencies.

To create a deb package from a Python one use https://pypi.org/project/stdeb/.

If you want to distribute Python package from PyPI there is no way for the package to declare system dependencies. The only way to handle this is to document dependencies and let the user handle them.